# Dealing with large arrays without getting runtime error

Tags: c, arrays, runtime, segmentation-fault

I am getting runtime error when I used array of size 10^5*10^5 (ex. `int a[100000][100000]`. As this array is consuming more memory, this may be one one of the reasons for runtime error.

How should I declare this array (2D array ex. `int a[100000][100000]`) so that I can cope with problem of `SIGSEGV` runtime error?

Please, provide approach to declare such type of array?

Comment: you are allocating 80GB of memory here, unless the machine has that much virtual RAM, at is at least one of the problems

Comment: Dynamic allocation is also giving runtime error for this array size , when I tried to submit solution in online coding plafeorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three ways to declare the large array `int a[100000][100000]` are:

1. Make the large array global
2. Make the large array `static`:

   ```
   static int a[100000][100000];
   ```
3. Use `malloc`/`calloc` and dynamically allocate the large array:

   ```
   int **a;
   a=malloc(sizeof(int*)*100000);
   for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
       a[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);

   /*Use the array*/

   for(int i=0;i<100000;i++)
       free(a[i]);
   free(a);
   ```